Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)
I have a Web application that I made in Visual Studio 2022, using .NET Core 8.0 and Angular 8, and the Azure Cognitive Services Speech (version 1.41.1) installed through NuGet. The application works fine in the local environment, but when I publish it in the development computer, or a target computer, the following error message appears:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)
Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Internal.SpeechConfig.speech_config_from_subscription(out IntPtr config, string subscriptionKey, string region)
Both the development computer and target computer (Windows 10) are using the same CPU architecture (64-bit). The target architecture is set to 'Any CPU'. My Target Computer has Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x64) and as well as (x86)  version 14.14.26405.
I am not sure what I am missing, here.
Thanks in advance.

Please share your .csproj file.

I had added the Package Reference in .csproj file.


add ```

PreserveNewest



win-x64;win-x86



The error Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll' typically occurs when the native dependencies required by the Azure Cognitive Services Speech SDK are not available or correctly configured in the deployment.
You can update your project.csproj file as shown below:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;win-x86</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <!-- Specify runtime identifiers -->
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech" Version="1.41.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- Ensure native DLLs are copied to the output directory -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)runtimes\**\native\*.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Additionally, run the following commands in your project path:

dotnet workload update
dotnet dev-certs https --trust

Rebuild the solution and redeploy it.


The dotnet workload update command is used to update the .NET SDK workloads to their latest versions. It adds support for multiple platforms (Android, iOS, macOS, Windows, WebAssembly).


After Installing Microsoft Visual c++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64) and (x32) in the server. Issue resolved. Thank you so much.

@BharathiDasan Good to accept the solution if it has solved the problem. This is for the benefit of the SO Community, refer SO Link
